# I got an issue in wifite how to solve it

Tags: drivers

After installing tshark, reaver, cowpatty and pyrit it shows me

```
[+] scanning for wireless devices...
 [!] no wireless interfaces were found.
 [!] you need to plug in a wifi device or install drivers.
```

How to fix this?